# How to send a message on a socket in color in C?

Tags: c, sockets

In `utils.h` I have these color codes:

```
#define RED   "\x1B[31m"
#define GRN   "\x1B[32m"
#define YEL   "\x1B[33m"
#define BLU   "\x1B[34m"
#define MAG   "\x1B[35m"
#define CYN   "\x1B[36m"
#define WHT   "\x1B[37m"
#define RESET "\x1B[0m"
```

And in `main.c` I'm sending messages to several sockets like this:

```
send(client_socket[caller], messageToCaller, strlen(messageToCaller), 0);
```

I know it's possible to print to stdout in color using (for example) `printf(RED "test message\n" RESET);`, but is there a convenient way to use `send` to send messages in color to sockets?

Edit: minor clarification (by output, I meant stdout)

Comment: These "colors" are just strings, and you can send strings via sockets, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Sockets dont have colors. you send bytes("octets") and the reciever can decide what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way, the color with `printf()` is handle by your shell. If you send the correct byte code in the socket and print it into a shell that is compatible with these code. That should work without problem.

However, this is the first time I ever see someone want to do that, and it's highly bizarre ;)

```
// send side

#define X (RED "test message\n")
send(client_socket[caller], X, sizeof X - 1, 0);
#undef X

// recv side

ssize_t n = recv(...);
if (n < 0) { /* error */ }
buffer[n] = '\0';
printf("%s", buffer);
```